# If $n$ is composite then $n$ divides $(n-1)!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We need to prove that if $n$ is a composite number $>4$, then $n|(n-1)!$. I wanted to ask if my observation is correct or not. What I think is that the statement can be reduced to $n|(n-2)!$ Because $n$ and $n-1$ are always co-prime.

Answer (score 3):

That is true. But it's perhaps easier to note that $n = (n-a)(n-b)$ for some $a$ and $b$. Clearly, if $a \ne b$ both $(n-a)$ and $(n-b)$ are factors of $(n-1)!$. It's a little more complicated if $a=b$.

Edit: if $a=b$, since $n>4$ we have $2(n-a) < (n-a)(n-b)$, so $(n-a)$ and $2(n-a)$ are both factors of $(n-1)!$. Thus $2(n-a)^2$ is a factor of $(n-1)!$ so $n=(n-a)^2$ must also be a factor of $(n-1)!$.

Comment: More precisely, $n-a$ and $2(n-a)$ are distinct integers each less than $n$, so their product divides $(n-1)!$ (the fact that they are both factors does not imply that their product is...)

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$(n-1)!=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots(n-2)\cdot(n-1)$$